# jQuery datatables execute code after onSort event

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I have this code (which works):

```
    $('#rooms').dataTable({
        "bFilter": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "bInfo": false
    });
```

What's working already is that the user can sort the HTML table by clicking on the column header.
However, after the sort is complete, I want to execute this code:

```
    $("#rooms tr:even").css("background-color", "#eeeeee");
    $("#rooms tr:odd").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
```

How can I do so?

Comment: Why not use CSS to change the background-color for `#rooms tr.odd` and `#rooms tr.even` ?

Comment: Sometimes it's soo easy! Thanks :)